# Axios with Vue access http instead of https

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am using vue2 and axios to make my ajax calls. In a page I am calling various ajax calls, **some go as HTTPS while others go through HTTP**, although both codes are similar.

Example:

```
        axios.get('/api/' + app.$variable1 + '/get-something/')
        .then(({ data }) =>
        {
            app.array = [];

            for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                app.vats.push({
                    id:data[i]['id'],
                    name:data[i]['name'],
                    something_else[i]['something_else']
                });
            }
        })
```

Question:
How can I *force Axios* to take HTTPS?

Objs:
I cannot manually add https, as such: "https://www.example.com/1234/12" because I am  using relative urls (I have certain id's assigned at url, and reuse them to make my calls).

Server:
1) I am forcing Https through htaccess
2) I am also using Secure Headers which does not allow the browser to get out of "self"

EDIT:

So trying to get down to the issue:
1) In the Mounted method I am calling 4 individual API's. The first two fail due to HTTP, and the last two get through. I tried chaning the order, and its always the first two to fail. I tried to move the code to Created, which makes less sense, and sure enough it did not work.

HELP!!

Comment: This snippet is nowhere enough to diagnose this. Do you have an htaccess or something _sometimes_ forcing https?

Comment: Yes, I am forcing https plus I am also using secure headers which does not allow browser to leave the current domain (https).

Comment: Since you are using relative urls, you should make your sever force the page to be https in the first place with url rewrite in iis or express-force-ssl in express.   It sounds like you are allowing http traffic in some scenario, possibly from a server running in a dev environment.

Comment: @LeoBartkus , Thats what I thought, but the Vue+Axios is calling Http, and the browser is blocking it. That means that the call never reached the server.

Comment: any luck over here?

Answer (score 1):

Add an [Axios request interceptor](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) and change the `config.url` from http to https. All requests will be intercepted and you will have access to the base URL scheme.

```
  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://api.com',
  })

  instance.interceptors.request.use(function(config) {
    // change the url scheme from http to https
    config.url = config.url.replace('http://', 'https://')

    return config
  })
```

Comment: Just my two cents: it is impossible to do vice versa: https to http. See this answer of Julien Ambrosio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74756751/cant-send-a-axios-request-from-https-to-http-server